# Converting string to char and int data types

Tags: c++, type-conversion

I've populated a string vector with with numbers and characters (`*,+,-,/`). I want to assign each number and character to two new vector, and `int` vector and a `char` vector. Is there a way to convert the everything from string to the desired data type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use string stream in the `<sstream>` header.

```
string myString = "123";
stringstream sStream( myString );
int convertedInt;
sStream >> convertedInt.
```

Answer (score 0):

Include the `<sstream>` header and you can do something like this:

```
std::vector<std::string> stringVector = /* get data from somewhere */

std::vector<int> intVector;
std::vector<char> charVector;

for (std::vector<std::string>::const_iterator it = stringVector.begin(); it != stringVector.end(); it++)
{
    if (it->length() == 0)
        continue; // ignore any empty strings

    int intValue;
    std::istingstream ss(*it);
    if (ss >> someValue) // try to parse string as integer
        intVector.push_back(someValue); // int parsed successfully
    else
        charVector.pushBack((*it)[0]);
}
```

This assumes anything that cannot be parsed as an integer should be pushed into the char vector instead (so, `234`, `100000` and `-34` will be put into `intVector`, and `/`, `+` etc will be put into `charVector`). Only the first character of a non-integer value is pushed, so if you have `*hello` or `*123`, only `*` will be put into the `charVector`.

If you are using C++11, you can swap the `std::vector<std::string>::const_iterator` with `auto` to make it look a bit nicer.